# How to make redirect url works after login with oauth2

Tags: react-native, url, redirect, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing oauth2 for my react native app, I'm working with this library :
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth

I'm encountering a problem with redirect url, it doesn't bring me back to the app after login, I tried many URLs, and honestly I don't understand how it works or how it should be written. I read some articles about it but still don't get it.

Comment: This issue you are facing in iOS or android?

Comment: android ( I didn't test it with iOS yet ) , and btw I tested the whole process with Postman and it works perfectly ( after login I receive access and refresh token ..etc )

Comment: Are using testing everything in emulator?

Comment: yes I'm using an emulator

Comment: Please try it in real device i had faced this issue earlier. By the way did you add manifestplaceholder in gradle file?

Comment: I tried it now and it gives the same behavior ( it navigates to the redirect url ) , and yes I added manifestplaceholder in gradle, as I told you, I'm starting question the redirect url itself, I tried many , so either it navigates to url ( like in this case now ) or just nothing happens